# Is it possible to serve more than one django project under same domain?

Tags: django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I have a site say, `localdjangosite.com` and I already have a django application running on that domain at url `localdjangosite.com/site1/`. For this I have a virtual host set up inside apache `sites-available` directory as follows, I used mod_wsgi also.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site1 /path/to/the/django/codebase/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/the/django/codebase/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And with that, that `site1` is working well.

Now I want to have one more site under the same domain like `localdjangosite.com/site2/`. And when I tried to configure apache like below I face page not found error.

```
WSGIScriptAlias /site2 /path/to/the/django/codebase/for/site2/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/the/django/codebase/for/site2/>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When I configured like that and visited the url `localdjangosite.com/site2/`, It shows Page not found error and it displays the url configurations of the `site1` instead of `site2`. Here `site1` and `site2` are really two different django projects and they have different apps inside and server different purpose.

So I really don't understand what is going on? what is wrong?

Could someone please help me to understand it and host two or more django projects under same domain?

Comment: did you setup the right `DNS` entries for both apps ? prefer subdomains if possible `site1.localdjangosite.com` and `site2.localdjangosite.com` and also don't forget to add `*.localdjangosite.com` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` for both apps

Comment: @cizario, yeah I can try it in my dev machine that is okay. But in production I can't have subdomains and that is a problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just use different port, for example:
`localdjangosite.com:80` and `localdjangosite.com:84`